# How to call/execute a oracle stored procedure from powerbi desktop with with refcursor output?

Tags: oracle, powerbi-desktop

I am a newbie with power bi desktop, I want to call/execute a oracle stored procedure from powerbi desktop with with refcursor output.

So it is possible ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I've only tested out one solution, and it involves using the OLE DB data source instead of the Oracle data source option. OLE DB takes a connection string to query the database, and the extended properties gives you the option of returning a PL/SQL record set. Look in [OLE DB Features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15169/using.htm#OLEDB168) for reference and look for the PLSQLRSet property. That has to be set to TRUE or "1".

```
Connection string -> provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;data source=mySource;extended properties="PLSQLRSet=1"

SQL Statement -> { CALL my_stored_refcursor_function }
```

If you want to bind parameters to the function call, it seems impossible at the moment without hardcoding those in because the parameters are hidden from the data source. I couldn't find anything otherwise.